# Controller test that ignores certain methods in an action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

writing an Rspec controller test, but trying to ignore certain methods, namely ones that will actually post something onto a third party via an API (e.g., Mail Chimp or Google Drive).

For example my controller code:

```
def create
@request = Request.new(request_params)
if @request.save
  flash[:success] = true
  @request.save_spreadsheet
  RequestMailer.confirmation_email(@request, request.host_with_port).deliver
  redirect_to edit_request_path(@request.edit_id)
else
  render 'new'
end
end
```

Where save_spreadsheet is a method that saves to Google spreadsheet. When I'm testing the controller, for example like so:

```
describe "POST create - with valid data" do
    it "creates a new request" do
        expect{
            post :create, request: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:request)
        }.to change(Request,:count).by(1)
    end
end
```

I want to test the controller but not actually save the FactoryGirl data into the spreadsheet, which is what is currently happening. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can stub the method to make sure it get called.

```
expect(RequestMailer).to receive(:confirmation_email).with(anything)
post :create, request: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:request)
```

The above example assumes any argument, you can also specify them within `with`.

Comment: Wow ok thanks, I'm very new to this stubbing concept. Looking at what @pbrisbin wrote below as well, it seems like I'll need to make a number of other declarations and stubs, and won't be able to copy the code above exactly right?

Comment: I don't think that. What you are doing is controller test. Controller test is kind of functional test but not unit test, so it's totally acceptable to depend on other app things. In this very example, you just need to make sure RequestMailer to get called correctly. That's enough for one example. For other things you can write other tests.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but the other problem I'm having is that the save_spreadsheet method is called, so I'll need to stub that out to. If I'm extrapolating from your code, could I just write something like expect(GoogleDrive).to receive(:save_spreadsheet).with(anything); post :create, request...?

Comment: @james, from your code I can only see the RequreMailer part depends on external thing and need stub. For others I assume they are all internal. If you have difficulty on make `save_request` working you can stub it as `allow(Request).any_instance.to receive(:save_request).and_return(true)` but that is not nice.

Comment: Oh apologies there, save_spreadsheet is a method that is defined in the model to basically save the user-input info as a row in a spreadsheet on a Google Excel doc. it uses the GoogleDrive gem. My biggest problem now is that everytime I run a test, a new row gets entered in the Google spreadsheet, so if anything my priority is to stub out the save_spreadsheet method. Does that help clarify?

Comment: james, if this is the case I'm afraid you need heavy stub like pbrisbin mentioned, or check gems like VCR to mimic external services.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to stub a lot of things, which may be a smell -- so first consider how writing this test could be made easier, and what sort of implementation that would drive you to.

If you want to test this implementation as-is, you'll need something along these lines:

```
params = { ... }
request = Request.new(params)
request.stub(:save_spreadsheet)
Request.stub(:new).with(params).and_return(request)
mailer = double("Mailer")
mailer.stub(:deliver)
RequestMailer.stub(:confirmation_email).with(request, ...).and_return(mailer)

expect { post :create, request: params }.to change(Request, :count).by(1)
```

Comment: Thanks! So I'm curious it seems as if stubbing means that I can't use FactoryGirl. Is that correct? Or could I still write something like FactoryGirl.build(:request)? Sorry I just learned about stubbing. And what is this line trying to do?  Request.stub(:new).with(params).and_return(request)

Comment: Mocks/Stubs and Factories are two separate concepts, feel free to google them. A Factory is an object that creates other objects (like a User factory would create a User instance via `create(:user)`). Factories are what FactoryGirl provides. A Mock/Stub is an object standing in for some other object which knows how to answer specific methods (like `user = double("User", save: true)`). A Mock has an expectation a method will be called, while a Stub just quacks like some duck, but doesn't yell if not asked to quack.

Comment: `Request.stub(:new).with(params).and_return(request)` tells the `Request` object that, if `new` is called with `params` it should return the `request` object. With this stub in place, `@request` in your implementation code will be the `request` you've defined in your test -- this allows you to set further expectations on it, specifically making `save_spreadsheet` a no-op.